# Uninstall breaks unprivileged boot-up services (MDM and audio) - Linux Mint 16rc KDE

Tags: linux-mint, kde, display-manager

### After a wine install/uninstall audio is broken and MDM fails as a boot up service, but still works via sudo.  How should I trouble shoot?

---

Last night I installed Wine, installed then removed mono-complete (and it's dependencies) and then ran apptitude update which when finished made my system seem unstable so I rebooted.

Upon reboot, the system hangs on the LM logo. F2 shows that starting MDM failed. So I tried

```
apt-get uninstall MDM
apt-get intstall MDM
```

and rebooted, this didn't help so I tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Which also didn't help, however, if I open up another TTY I can use

```
sudo MDM
```

and MDM starts fine.

It seems quite similar to these bugs:

[Linux Mint fails to start X automatically after update, but X still works](https://superuser.com/questions/558974/linux-mint-fails-to-start-x-automatically-after-update-but-x-still-works)
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=141808

but I don't have infinality installed, nor can I detect any issues with mdm.conf

---

I'm not sure if this is related (and if not I'll start a new question), but upon login I noticed I no longer had sound. Clicking the sound system tray icon, I noticed that the mixer is now pointed to "Dumy Output". I tried to go to sound settings to reconfigure this, but there are no detected sound cards to choose.

Please let me know if any log files would be helpful.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if drivers are installed for your sound hardware.

Open /var/log/apt/history.log

Check what packages were removed. It sounds like you removed something that you need. I just realized this is pretty old. But in case it helps ...

Comment: sorry, I should have deleted this; I've re-installed with the actual Mint KDE 16 release and currently have no problems.  I'll try to edit this question to be more useful / solvable.

Answer (score 1):

I've been up all day trying to fix an error that I think is very similar to this. I searched all the related help sources to find out why MDM was not booting except when run with sudo (as in, it fails on boot and I enter terminal using alt-F6 and I type sudo mdm), and I found the following command fixes it:

sudo update-rc.d mdm defaults

Furthermore, back when I had to run mdm using sudo, my audio wouldn't work. Now after running the above command and having a proper boot, the audio works again.

Just as a caveat, I don't really know what I'm doing so it's not like I identified the problem in all its generality. On the other hand, I don't think there's any harm in running the above command because it's setting something or other to default.

Furthermore, I got this from Pela's answer on
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=141808

I just ran the update-rc.d command for mdm that I've listed above and I didn't bother with any of the other commands regarding the installation of infinality etc.

I hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, and none of the solutions here worked me. After many hours of struggling, and logs showing no errors, I found that my problem was (surprisingly) the result of an unrelated syntax error in `/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh`.

Fixing my script fixed the issue for me.